# Speeding up a SQL query with generic data information

Tags: sql, query-optimization

Due to a variety of design decisions, we have a table, 'CustomerVariable'.  CustomerVariable has three bits of information--its own id, an id to Variable (a list of possible settings the customer can have), and the value for that variable.  The Variable table, on the other hand, has the information on a default--in case the CustomerVariable is not set.

This works well in most situations, allowing us not to have to create an insanely long list of information--especially in a case where there are 16 similar variables that need to be handled for a customer.

The problem comes in trying to get this information into a select.  So far, our 'best' solution involves far too many joins to be efficient--we get a list of the 16 VariableIds we need information on, setting them into variables, first.  Later on, however, we have to do this:

```
   CROSS JOIN dbo.Variable v01
   LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerVariable cv01 ON cv01.customerId = c.id 
                                      AND cv01.variableId = v01.id
   CROSS JOIN dbo.Variable v02
   LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerVariable cv02 ON cv02.customerId = c.id 
                                      AND cv02.variableId = v02.id
   -- snip --
   CROSS JOIN dbo.Variable v16
   LEFT JOIN dbo.CustomerVariable cv16 ON cv16.customerId = c.id 
                                      AND cv16.variableId = v16.id
WHERE
   v01.id = @cv01VariableId
   v02.id = @cv02VariableId
   -- snip --
   v16.id = @cv16VariableId
```

I know there has to be a better way, but we can't seem to find it amidst crunch time.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How do you determine that there are too many joins to be efficient?

Comment: what is with the CROSS JOINS? show more of the query!

Comment: @rexem: I'm thinking 16 self joins qualifies. ;)

Comment: BTW, what SQL server are you using?

Comment: @Chris: If that's what's necessary based on the data model, then there isn't much that can be done.

Comment: @rexem:  The query itself runs slow, currently taking more than an hour to process on Customers.  We were hoping to find some way of optimizing it, so it would be shorter--given that this is a query we intend to run nightly.

Comment: __your question lacks many things necessary to solve this technical problem.__  it looks like SQL Server, but what database and version are you using? what are the table schemas? what indexes are defined? what is the entire query?  do you have an execution plan _SET SHOWPLAN_ALL ON_ to show us what is going on?  what are the approximate row counts of the tables involved? is this for all customers or just one? have you updated statistics recently? did you check to see if this is a locking/blocking problem or just a aslow query?

Comment: @rexem: The datamodel isn't exactly the problem.. The underlying server handling this is crucial.  Some servers don't have the functionality necessary to deal with data in this format. In which case you would be right that the joins are necessary.  However, most of them do have the proper functionality.  KM has the right questions for the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your data set is relatively small and not too volatile, you may want to use materialized views (assuming your database supports them) to optimize the lookup.

If materialized views are not an option, consider writing a stored procedure that retrieves that data in two passes:

1. First retrieve all of the CustomerVariables available for a particular customer (or set of customers)
2. Next, retrieve all of the default values from the Variables table
3. Perform a non-distinct union on the results merging the defaults in wherever a CustomerVariable record is missing.

Essentially, this is the equivalent of:

```
SELECT variableId, 
       CASE WHEN CV.variableId = NULL THEN VR.defaultValue ELSE CV.value END
FROM Variable VR
LEFT JOIN CUstomerVariable CV on CV.variableId = VR.variableId
WHERE CV.customerId = c.id
```

Comment: Incidentally, I've gone both routes (mine described above, and this one).  There are good things and bad things to both.  With the two pass method, you can actually respond faster to the browser, and easily terminate the loop to get the data if the user so chooses; however, the total query time is slower.  With the view route, it's easier to give direct query access for other applications.

Answer (score 1):

The type of query you want is called a [pivot table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pivot_table) or [crosstab](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crosstab) query.

By far the easiest way of dealing with this is to create a view based off of a crosstab query.  This will flip the columns from being vertical to being horizontal like a regular sql table.  Once that is done, just query the view.  Easy. ;)